# how to perform calculations on image raw data with CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, image-processing, filter, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to create specific custom filter effects on image for iOS. So far, I've been trying to get raw data using CGBitmapContextCreate. However, I don't really have an idea of how to modify my rawData. I hope to perform calculations on it. I hope to effect pixel by pixel with the rawData but I have no idea how to manipulate it.

I also don't know how I can draw my bitmap context to a UIImage, so I can render the finished product on an UIImageView.

Could somebody give me some pointers to how I might be able to achieve that?

Here's my code so far:

```
// First get the image into your data buffer
CGImageRef imageRef = imageView.image.CGImage;
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

//perform calculations on rawData? or context? not sure!! i hope to effect pixel by pixel.


//am i doing this correctly?
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//set the imageview with the new image
[imageView setImage:newImage];
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
You can perform your transactions on the RGB and Alpha channels via:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < rawDataSpace ; i+=4) {
        rawData[i+0] = ...              
        rawData[i+1] = ...            
        rawData[i+2] = ...             
        rawData[i+3] = ...       // = Alpha channel
```